# How to set a single recyclerview item [imageview] take half of the screen?

Tags: android

I have inflated recyclerview item from single_item.xml and it has only one imageview. How do i make it take half of the screen?
Or in another way, how can i show two items per screen in the main xml file that inflates single_item.xml file?
And i want to do this without setting fixed height.
I tried with layout weight division, but that disables the hosting view from displaying two item instead of one.

Comment: you can't do this through XML, but you can try doing that from the adapter code. When inflating the view, calculate half of the screen size, and set item height to that value

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to add code to `onCreateViewHolder()` that changes the item view's height (if you're using a vertical layout manager) or width (if you're using a horizontal layout manager).

Here's an example for how to make each item be half the size of the screen:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);

    // here we override the inflated view's height to be half the recyclerview size
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = (parent.getHeight() / 2) - layoutParams.topMargin - layoutParams.bottomMargin;
    itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

If your item view layout doesn't have any margins, you can leave off the subtraction of margins and just use

```
layoutParams.height = parent.getHeight() / 2;
```

If you're trying to use a horizontal layout manager instead, you'd change the width instead of the height:

```
layoutParams.width = (parent.getWidth() / 2) - layoutParams.leftMargin - layoutParams.rightMargin;
```